# value inside for loop not incrementing

Tags: c

The value inside the `for` loop `nn` turns to `0`, after it exits the loop. I expected it to increment as described in the loop. How do I make `nn` save it's value after exiting?

```
void branch(int *numbers, int left) {
    Int nb, nn;
    nb = 0;
    nn = 0;

    if (left != 0)
        for (int branchn = 1; branchn <= left; branchn++) {
            for (int index = 1; index <= branchn; index++) {
                *(buffer + nb) = *(buffer + nb) * 10 + *(numbers + nn++);
                printf("%d\n", nn);
            }

            nb++;
            length++;

            branch(numbers, left - 1);
        }
    else {
        branchop(length--);
        nb--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make it `static`. Or better yet pass it as a parameter to the function. Or better yet, get rid of this ineffective code, that may or may not tail optimize, and replace it all with a simple for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has multiple problems and its design is very confusing:

- what is an `Int`?
- what are the definitions of `buffer`, `length` and `branchop()`?
- why do you use 1 based offsets?  Array indexing is 0 based in C.
- why do you use recursion?
- `nn` and `nb` are local variables with automatic storage in `branch()`; each new recursive call has its own set of these variables.  You might want to make these `static` so they are shared by all calls, including recursive ones, but the code would become even more convoluted.

I cannot provide a corrected version of the code, because you did not give any clue as to what it is supposed to achieve and it is difficult to tell from the posted fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it works as designed.

You are recursively calling `branch()` and `branch()` will set `nn` to `0` on startup of the method. When you finally leave the recursive `branch()`, `nn` will have the assigned, incremented value of inside the `for()` loop.